# export and maintain vue application

Tags: vue.js, export

I have developed a vue application and did run `npm run build`
After that I uploaded the content in the dist file to my webpage but it returned a blank page.

Since I did this for testing I uploaded it to a folder in my `public_html/mypage.com/vueapplication` To get all the paths right I added  a `vue.config.js` with this content:

```
// vue.config.js

module.exports = {
     publicPath: '/vueapplication/'
}
```

The application now works but I wounder however:

1. how do I best publish/upload the application to my site? Just by simply dragging the content inte the right folder?
2. how can I best maintain my site? Do I need to build again and upload, overwriting my files when everytime I make an update on my site?
3. And what is the difference between build and deploy your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Drag and dropping your code should work. But as your app grows you may want to look into automating this. For instance if you use an S3 bucket you can use the **aws cli** to automate the upload.
2. Yes, you should overwrite your deploy folder(s). You need to also take care of deploying different binary files, that have the same name. An example is if you have a global css file (main.css for instance). The file will probably change content between deployments, but keep the same name. Browsers may [cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching) the file so users that downloaded older versions of the file will not use the new one. There are different techniques to handle this, but if you use webpack, it uses cache busting techniques and you should be fine.
3. Build is the process of transforming source code into an artifact(s). Exactly what this means differs from language to language, platform to platform. In the vuejs world this usually means a couple of js files, a couple of css files and some assets.

   Deploying means taking the output of a build and making it available to your users. Again this differs from project to project. In the vuejs world this usually means taking the artifacts from the build and uploading them to an http enabled web server.